# Fazer Scraping de um Html Externo

Tags: c#, scraping

Estou tentando pegar um texto de um outro site usando C# (HtmlAgilityPack).

Eu consigo encontrar a div, mas quando tento mostrar na tela o valor, ele mostra o caminho da função.

Acredito que estou esquecendo de algum trecho de código.

Segue meu Controller:

```
public class TesteDeScrapingController : Controller
{
    // GET: TesteDeScraping
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument html = web.Load("https://www.climatempo.com.br/previsao-do-tempo/cidade/583/araguaina-to");

        var div = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@id='tempMax0']");

        ViewBag.Div = div;

        return View();
    }
}
```

Segue meu HTML:

```
<h2>Teste</h2>
<div>
    @ViewBag.Div
</div>
```

Comment: fazendo isso você dentro da sua div será como pegar um DocumentNode e chamar o método ToString() nele. Acho que basta você chamar a propriedade `InnerHtml`: `@ViewBag.Div.InnerHtml`

Comment: @RovannLinhalis função traz o nome da Collection. Consegui resolver, vou postar como uma resposta caso alguém precise no futuro. Valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: Não tem uma relação direta com sua dúvida, mas no caso do exemplo dado, do clima tempo, eles possuem uma API para acessar os dados, sem a necessidade de fazer essa leitura de HTML: http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, a função devolve uma collection e eu estava tratando como uma string, por isso ele devolvia o nome da collection.

Apenas acrescentei um foreach para pegar o conteúdo da collection.
Ficou assim:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument html = web.Load("https://www.climatempo.com.br/previsao-do-tempo/cidade/583/araguaina-to");

        var div = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@id='tempMax0']");
        var conteudo = string.Empty;

        foreach(var conteudos in div)
        {
            conteudo = conteudos.InnerHtml;
        }

        ViewBag.Div = conteudo;

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: entendi, mas verifica seu código que tem coisa desnecessária... se está buscando um elemento pelo id, deveria retornar apenas um elemento, e não uma coleção. Talvez usar outro método ao invés de `SelectNodes`

Comment: Faz sentido @RovannLinhalis. Vou pesquisar sobre o assunto.